# Formatting differences

Tags: powershell

I have two blocks of code:

```
$allUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter *
foreach($_ in $allUsers.Name){
    Write-Host "User $_ is member of the following groups:" -for Yellow
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_ | select Name,objectClass,Groupscope,Groupcategory | sort Name | Format-Table
}
User Administrator is member of the following groups:

Name                 objectClass                  Groupscope       Groupcategory
----                 -----------                  ----------       -------------
Administrators       group                       DomainLocal            Security
Distributed COM U... group                       DomainLocal            Security
Domain Admins        group                            Global            Security
Domain Users         group                            Global            Security
Enterprise Admins    group                         Universal            Security
Group Policy Crea... group                            Global            Security
HelpLibraryUpdaters  group                       DomainLocal            Security
Schema Admins        group                         Universal            Security


User Guest is member of the following groups:

Name                 objectClass                  Groupscope       Groupcategory
----                 -----------                  ----------       -------------
Domain Guests        group                            Global            Security
Guests               group                       DomainLocal            Security
```

The other version looks like this:

```
    $allUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter *
    foreach($_ in $allUsers.Name){
        Write-Host "User $_ is member of the following groups:"
        Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_ | select Name,objectClass,Groupscope,Groupcategory | sort Name
    }

User Administrator is member of the following groups:

Name                 objectClass                  Groupscope       Groupcategory
----                 -----------                  ----------       -------------
Administrators       group                       DomainLocal            Security
Distributed COM U... group                       DomainLocal            Security
Domain Admins        group                            Global            Security
Domain Users         group                            Global            Security
Enterprise Admins    group                         Universal            Security
Group Policy Crea... group                            Global            Security
HelpLibraryUpdaters  group                       DomainLocal            Security
Schema Admins        group                         Universal            Security
User Guest is member of the following groups:
Domain Guests        group                            Global            Security
Guests               group                       DomainLocal            Security
```

The latter is easier to read in my opinion. My question is this is; Why does the first block of code show the headers for each user? The way I see it, the select-object is called for every user in $allUsers.Name, so the headers should be shown every time in the latter one aswell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is the number of times `Format-Table` is called. In the first example it is called for each user. This means the headers are printed for each user. In the second example `Format-Table` is called only once so the headers are only printed once.

The second command has an implied `Format-Table` at the end, so if you do this:

```
$allUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter *
foreach($_ in $allUsers.Name){
    Write-Host "User $_ is member of the following groups:"
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_ | select Name,objectClass,Groupscope,Groupcategory | sort Name
} | Format-Table
```

You should get the same results.

Comment: Didn't know that Format-Table was implied. Thanks.